# how to keep track of previous touch location(cocs2d)?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to select a sprite and move that to the next touch location.

**How do I keep track of the two seperate touch location?**

Answer (score 1):

Add an ivar:

```
CGPoint previousLocation;
```

Update it at the end of the touch methods with the current location:

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan … etc
{
    …
    previousLocation = touchLocation;
}
```